# URL redirects on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

I have added a new webpage to my web site.i need to redirect users who request the old page ti the newly added page for example if user requests the page

```
http://www.mysite.com/foo.aspx

user should be redirected to

http://www.mysite.com/bar/default.aspx
```

how can i use use IIS 7 to achieve this?

Comment: Why on Earth was this downvoted? It's a well-formed question, politely asked and to the point. Questions should not be downvoted because the asker is a noob.

Answer (score 1):

add url mapping in web.config

in my site:

```
<urlMappings enabled="true"> 
<add url="~/RSS" mappedUrl="~/rss.axd"/> 
</urlMappings>
```

redirect request `http://mydomain/RSS` to `http://mydomain/rss.axd`

Answer (score 0):

You sure can, here is the relevant documentation at microsoft on how to set it up

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732969(v=ws.10).aspx